# Invoke Custom AuthenticationHandler before middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core WebAPI (2.2) which uses **two** types of Authentication:

- JWTBearer
- APIKey (Custom)

This is how I configure it within the **Startup.cs**:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddApiKeyAuthentication(options => Configuration.Bind("ApiKeyAuth", options));

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
{
    jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0/";
    jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
    jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
    };
});
```

My controllers are decorated with an `Authorize` attribute that includes both schemes. So I am able to invoke my web methods using either, a bearer token or by specifying an API key in the header - That works fine.

Now I added a custom middleware where I perform some tenant-specific checks. I registered the middleware inside the `Configure` method (after `UseAuthentication`):

```
// ....
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>()
```

Now if I invoke a REST method using **bearer** authentication, my `CustomMiddleware` gets called with an authenticated user - *I can* access the claims.

If I invoke the *same* REST method using my custom **APIKey** authentication, my `CustomMiddleware` gets called **before** my `AuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()` method. The User *is not* authenticated - I *can't* access the claims (which I populate myself inside the `HandleAuthenticateAsync` method).

Why gets the middleware called before the authentication? How can I change that behavior so that the middleware gets called **after** the `HandleAuthenticateAsync()`?

Comment: Is JwtBearer configured as the default authentication scheme? Your code snippets don't show how you've set up default schemes.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks for your help. I added my exact configuration.

Comment: For the REST method in question, is it an MVC action with the `[Authorize]` attribute. If it's not, what is it? I realise there's going to be more than one affected method, but it's easier to work with a specific example.

Comment: All my controllers uses an CustomeAuthorize attribute that inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute` and sets the `AuthenticationSchemes` to `AuthenticationSchemes = "ApiKey,Bearer";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to setup a forward default selector to make the API key authentication scheme the default when necessary.

Here is an example of that:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
{
    jwtOptions.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Policy"]}/v2.0/";
    jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
    jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
    };
    jwtOptions.ForwardDefaultSelector = ctx =>
    {
        if (ctx.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Api-Key", out var headerValues))
        {
            return "ApiKeyAuth";
        }

        return null;
    };
})
.AddApiKeyAuthentication(options => Configuration.Bind("ApiKeyAuth", options));
```

I made some guesses to construct the selector,
but basically it needs to return the name of another scheme if another should be used,
and null otherwise.

In the example it checks if an "Api-Key" header is on the request,
and if yes, returns "ApiKeyAuth" which is the API key scheme's name.
Swap those to your values if they are different.

If in both schemes an Authorization: Bearer xyz header was used,
you would need to inspect the header contents in the selector to make the decision.